# Wrapping my head around IEnumerable & IEnumerator

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ienumerator

So getting back into Coding after a long hiatus being Network admin ... and learning C# (and Unity) as I go.  Trying to wrap my head around `IEnumerable` & `IEnumerator`

Now, here's sample code of the class I'm using to test/figure it out ... it works, creates the tree/leaf nodes recursively however I'm stuck on retrieving them

```
public class NodeTest : IEnumerable
{
   public int Counter;
   public List<NodeTest> children;

   public NodeTest(int count)
   {
        Counter = count;
        Debug.Log("Creating " + count);
        NodeTest tmpNode;

     if(count>1)
     {
        children = new List<NodeTest>();
        tmpNode = new NodeTest(Counter - 1);
        children.Add(tmpNode);
        tmpNode = new NodeTest(Counter - 1);
        children.Add(tmpNode);      
     }
 }

 public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
 {
     foreach(NodeTest n in this.children)
     {
         yield return n;
     }
 }
}
```

Then in the elsewhere I use :

```
foreach(NodeTest nt in tstNode)
{
   Debug.Log(nt.Counter);
}
```

Which retrieves the top node's children just fine but doesn't iterate through the children to get their children etc.   I'm guessing I have to do more in the `IEnumerator` `GetEnumerator` method?

Comment: If all your items are from type NodeTest why do you choose to use the interface IEnumerable of the more specific and easier to consume IEnumerable<NodeTest> which would also allow you to easily use LINQ with your results.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `NodeTest.GetEnumerator` a recursive method. As well as returning each child, you need to get each child to return all of its children. (Which will make each child's child return its children etc).

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    foreach(NodeTest n in this.children)
    {
       yield return n;
       foreach(NodeTest descendent in n)
       {
           yield return descendent;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Note that this returns the parent *before* the descendants - depending on the business requirement, you can move `yield return n;` below the inner `foreach`.

Comment: Oh my why didn't I think of that ... thanks Andrew and Comintern

Comment: It should be pointed out that this code is correct, but using recursive yield returns should be avoided because they can become extremely inefficient.  If you recurse 20 levels deep, that means each item has to be passed back through 20 levels of yield return to get to the original foreach, and then step back in through 20 levels to get to the next item.  Although if you're only recursing a few levels deep, it shouldn't matter too much.

Comment: Yes, at most it'll be 5-9 layers deep ... BSP Tree.    Andrew's code throws me an error though as I had the children = new List<NodeTest> before the check if I'd reached the limit of my recursion.